# ASP.NET Web API - Distinguish between route / query params

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Have this Web API controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/echo")]
public class EchoController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userId}/{message}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Echo(string userId, string message, string queryString)
    {
        await Task.Delay(150);
        return Ok(new {Action = "Echo", UserId = userId, Message = message, QueryString = queryString});
    }
}
```

A legit route executing this API would look like this: `/api/echo/johni/hello?querystring=1`

As you can see, this dummy API receives 3 inputs:

1. `userId` from the route
2. `message` from the route
3. `querystring` from the query params

All 3 of them, are available as dictionary here: `httpActionContext.ActionArguments`.

---

Question is, given the `HttpActionContext`, how would one distinguish between the route / query parameters?

Comment: Just curious - Is there a specific reason you would want to know which one is a route vs querystring using `HttpActionContext`?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a response cache middleware and I'd like to add a feature to ignore query params (only).

Comment: Interesting. Am only aware of the `HttpContext` available in .net core that has `HttpContext.Request` object which in turn has the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

- **X** = `httpActionContext.ActionArguments` - all parameters (route / query).
- **Y** = `httpActionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values` - route parameters only.

Which means, **X - Y** - query params only.

Comment: Where did you set this settings?